# Answering these particular questions will earn you extra badges!

Tags: discussion, participation, site-stats, unanswered-questions

**Bronze** [revival](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revival):

- [What are the methods for calculating solvation effects in free energies and how do they compare?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/551/5)
- [How to find the projected Hamiltonian for lowest flat-band in general?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/689/5)
- [Derivatives with respect to user defined vibrational modes](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/778/5)
- [Why do interaction potential parametrizations of bulk systems not work for corresponding nano-systems?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/831/5)
- [What are typical RPA capabilities of plane-wave codes?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/838/5)
- [How to set up a local server for iQmol on macOS?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/879/5)
- [What is band inversion and how to recognize it in band structure?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/909/5)
- [Generating interatomic potentials via force matching](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/950/5)
- [Which basis set families were optimized to give the lowest possible variational energy for a given number of orbitals?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/953/5)
- [How to understand dynamical spin structure factor?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1003/5)
- [What is the formula for calculating the local dielectric constant from MD output?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1081/5)
- [Avoiding charge-migration in electronic structure calculations with solvent-like environments](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1094/5)
- [Benchmark transition state geometries in condensed phases](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1197/5)

**Silver** [necromancer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancer):

- [What kind of information can be extracted from alloy microstructure images converted to Fourier space?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/35/5)
- [Where/when did the fields of Operations Research and Materials Modeling begin to cross-pollinate?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/136/5)
- [How can reactivity indices be calculated in a time-dependent scheme?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/305/5)
- [Alternatives to VEDA 4 vibrational energy distribution analysis software?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/411/5)
- [Fermi level change in surfaces with adsorbed molecules](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/428/5)
- [How to calculate t-zero temperature using Thermo-Calc- Python (TCPython) for multiple alloys?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/483/5)